# Excel VBA macro that finds newline and adds a new row?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Selection.Replace What:="" & Chr(10) & "", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I have a spreadsheet with multiple cells that contain multiple newlines ( the little question mark box symbol). What I'm trying to do is find all the newlines add a new row for each newline found and paste the content after the newline into the new row. I'm new to macros so I tried recording one to try to understand it. Right now the above code is finding the new line and replacing it with a space in the same cell. Not sure how to go about adding the new row?

Comment: So, you have a tab in an Excel file with multiple tables.  You want to loop through all the tables and add data in a new row.  Is that correct?  (also +1 for trying the macro recorder first)

Comment: Excuse my noobishness, tab meaning sheet and tables meaning columns? If so, yes. I only have one worksheet in the excel file with cells in more than one column containing the newline character. So for example cell A2 is Station_Number 1 and cell B2 contains the strike and dip: "N 77 E 79 SE?N 86 E 37 NW". The newly inserted row 3 needs to contain all the other info in row 2 with just "N 86 E 37 NW" in the B3 cell. Seems like this is going to be more than just a simple find and replace. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying now.  My first attempt was wrong. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer.  It is for a **single cell**

Select a cell containing text with included hard returns and run:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, HR As String
    Set r = Selection(1)
    v = r.Value
    HR = Chr(10)
    If InStr(v, HR) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    ary = Split(v, HR)
    For i = 1 To UBound(ary)
        r.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    Next i
    For i = 0 To UBound(ary)
        r.Offset(i, 0).Value = ary(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

You should embed this in loop(s) to cover all the cells in question.

Comment: Thank you this helps. A couple questions I see you created a variable s but it isn't used. What is that for? How would I modify this to go to the cell below if it doesn't meet the If statement instead of exiting the macro? I added a do until loop to your code that once the syntax is correct will go through every cell in the column needed.

Comment: 'Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, HR As String, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D2").Select
    Set r = Selection(1)
    v = r.Value
    HR = Chr(10)
    Do
    If InStr(v, HR) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    ary = Split(v, HR)
    For i = 1 To UBound(ary)
        r.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    Next i
    For i = 0 To UBound(ary)
        r.Offset(i, 0).Value = ary(i)
    Next i
    Loop Until r = lastRow
End Sub
'